# Mysqli query inside php function to check userlevel

Tags: php, session, mysqli

I'm trying to make a function that checks the user level.

```
function run_admin($userid, $username){

    global $dbcon;

    $stmt = $dbcon->prepare("SELECT userid, username, admin FROM user WHERE userid = ?");

    $stmt->bind_param('isi',$userid, $username, $admin);
    $userid = $_SESSION['userID'];

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($userid,$username,$admin);

    $stmt->fetch();

   //if($admin >= 1){ echo $userid . " is admin!"; }
   // above prints "1 is admin!";

}

if(run_admin("1", "Mikkel") == "1")){ 
   echo "It's working, you are admin"; 
}
```

I've included the file with the $dbcon and it is working on another page. The global is a idea from another question, [mysqli/mysql query inside function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836078/mysqli-mysql-query-inside-function-not-working?rq=1) but I can't get it working.

I'd like to use the function to check if session logged in userID and username .

The admin row returns with integers.

I'm not really good at mysqli prepared statements, still learning but this I don't know where to read about.

Could anyone help or guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Wouldn't you like get an error message or something? You have bound too many unused parameters. Read up on PDO before getting too entangled with mysqli.

Comment: Oh sorry. It should be bind_param('i', $userid) with userid as it in the where clause. It is working I just pasted to much from test.

Comment: omg it's working .. I just read from another q that I could use; ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); to see error messages.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in this statements :

```
$stmt = $dbcon->prepare("SELECT userid, username, admin FROM user WHERE userid = ?");

$stmt->bind_param('isi',$userid, $username, $admin);
```

In the first statement, in your query there is only one `?` for the **userid**, so in the second statement you need to bind only one value. So the statement will be :

```
$stmt->bind_param('i',$userid);
```

Comment: Thanks, I know. Look at my comment to the Q. I pasted too much from my tests .. :( Nothing is wrong with the query, my question is how to make the function work proberly :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd compact your code:

```
function is_admin($userid) {
    return
        db("SELECT admin FROM user WHERE userid = ?", $userid)
        ->admin;
}

if (is_admin("1")) { 
   echo "It's working, you are admin"; 
}
```

This is using a simple [db()/PDO wrapper](http://fossil.include-once.org/hybrid7/wiki/db). It's probably unsuitable for you. But just pick ***any*** database abstraction scheme. - While of course you could choose to keep the long-winded `mysqli` instead. (Yikes!)

The important point is [`return`ing](http://php.net/return) the `admin` column. Your excerpt didn't do that. Which is why the [`if`](http://php.net/if) failed to work.

Also avoid `== "1"` in comparisons. Your database already returns a boolean or integer. And PHP is perfectly apt to evaluate it in boolean context even if it came back as string.

Comment: Very nice comment. Thanks :-)
but learning how mysqli works are more important for me, than using a shortcut .. at least at the begininng :)

Comment: Learning things in detail is obviously a good thing. Mysqli however is a waste of time, and quite often a newcomer trap IMO. Nobody is using it for new projects. The PHP community at large has settled on PDO.