# use mysqli in a function global variable does not work

Tags: php, mysqli

if I use the following code everything works:

```
function likecount($id) {
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'printstagram');
    $query = $link->query("SELECT likes FROM photos WHERE id='$id'");
    $a = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
    $b=$a[0];
    echo $b;
}
```

if I use a file called dbconfig.php which has the following code:

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'printstagram');
```

and then I include dbconfig.php on the php page where I use the likecount function, then uses the global keyword:

```
function likecount($id) {
    global $link;
    $query = $link->query("SELECT likes FROM photos WHERE pid='$id'");
    $a = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
    $b=$a[0];
    echo $b;
}
```

I got an error:mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given．

Can someone tell me where could the error come from? The function is responsible for counting and updating the number of likes. If I use mysqli_connect every time the function is called, I will use mysqli_connect many times in a page, is that an issue? Comparing with global $link, i believe establishing a connection every time the function is called will add more pressure to the server.

I conducted some further testing, for the following code:

```
<?php
include('dbconfig.php');
global $link;
echo $link;
?>
```

I got:Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string. 
Is this considered an ordinary behavior?

I conducted another testing, the following code will work smoothly(but it will establish a connection every time the function is called):

```
<?php

function likes2($id) {
　　$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'printstagram');

    $query = $link->query("SELECT likes FROM photos WHERE pid='$id'");

    $a = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
    $b=$a[0];
    echo $b;

}
?>
```

but the following doesn't:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'printstagram');
function likes2($id) {

    global $link;
    $query = $link->query("SELECT likes FROM photos WHERE pid='$id'");
    $a = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
    $b=$a[0];
    echo $b;

}
?>
```

it gives the error: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: error saying your query has failed to execute

Comment: I know that but I want to know why it failed. I looked at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836078/mysqli-mysql-query-inside-function-not-working  and I don't know why their codes works but mine doesn't

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code as far as I can tell, it likely due to your database, show your `photo` database schema or database content. The error is suggesting that your `mysql_fetch_row($qeury)` didn't yield any result.

Comment: Hi hchueng, if there is something wrong with my database, it shouldn't work "optionally".  the problem is as long as I establish a new mysqli connection every time the function is called, everything works smoothly, but if I use global $link it doesn't

Comment: What does `echo $link->error();` print out when you put it inside your `likecount` function just after the link with `$link->query()`?

Comment: call to undefined method mysqli:error()

Comment: @gravition: sorry for that, it should be just `echo $link->error;`

Comment: @JiriHrazdil I got : Commands out of sync, you can't run this command right now

Comment: Great, do a Stack Overflow search with this error message and find yourself a solution (as it is hidden in the code you have not shown us, we cannot be of any more help here).

Answer (score 0):

this is index.php like that

```
require "dbconnect.php";
function likecount($item_id) {
    global $link;
    $query = $link->query("SELECT likes FROM photos WHERE pid='$item_id'");
    $a = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
    $b=$a[0];
    echo $b;
}
likecount($item_id);
```

this is dbconnect.php

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'printstagram')
```

Comment: i think you selected  "SELECT likes FROM photo" likes is unknown column . please check it again

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your both code are working fine!. The problem may with your database name, you using two different database "test" and "printstagram" may be "printstagram" photos table of database printstagram dont have records for which id you are searching.

You can check if there is record like this.

```
if($a = mysqli_fetch_row($query)){
    $b=$a[0];
    echo $b;
}
```